# Create a grouped bar chart with multiple measures by color

Tags: tableau-api

I'd like to create a grouped bar chart with multiple measures by color. I have the following measures:

```
Clicks
Impressions
Revenue
Profit
```

I have a total of 2 web sites that I am collecting data from, so I'd like to have a different color for each measure and the columns to be side-by-side. Also, I'd like for them to be separated by site as well.

I see the stacked bar columns, but that's not the way I want to visualize this. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I Understood, you have 4 measures, 1 dimension(***Websites***) with 2 websites names. Now, you need to show side by side bar, each column has two websites i.e., 4 columns with 2 sub columns each.

Drag ***Measure Names*** and ***Websites*** to columns shelf and ***Measure Values*** to row shelf.
Now, from `Show Me` shelf select `side-by-side bars`
If you get 2 columns with 4 sub columns, swap positions of ***Measure Names*** and ***Websites***. 
If you didn't get different colors for different measures, drag ***Measure Names*** to **Color** in `Marks`.

hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Just like Y.Prithvi said, you would use **measure names** and **measure values**.

(disregard the fields in the filters card, I filtered my data to match what you were trying to accomplish)

See example:

[image]